# Read file in php and set it to the img src in html

Tags: php, html

How can I read a file from the images folder(permissions 644) on the server in php and set it dynamically to the img src of html ?
I have tried the following

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    $name = './images/approved.jpg';
    //$fp = readfile($name);
    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($name);

    echo "<img src='data:image/jpg;base64,+ 'base64_encode($im), alt='Approved Videos''>";

    exit;
?>
```

I have also tried the following

```
<div id="videoThumbnails">
                        <p>Thumbnail</p>
                        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                   <!-- <img src="/phpVA/thumbnails/a.mp4.jpg" alt="Denied Videos">-->
                                   <?php 
                                        $name="/phpVA/thumbnails/a.mp4.jpg";
                                        $im = file_get_contents($name);
                                        echo "<img src='data:image/jpg;base64,".base64_encode($im)."' alt='Approved Videos'>";
                                    ?>
                        </a>

                      </div>
```

Output is

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64," alt="Approved Videos">
```

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Comment: @kamalpal Ive edited my question to include what I have tried so far

Answer (score 1):

Try `file_get_contents`

```
$im = file_get_contents($name);
echo "<img src='data:image/jpg;base64,".base64_encode($im)."' alt='Approved Videos'>";
```

Comment: Hi @Damien It gives me file_get_contents() : failed to open stream permission denied . What permissions should I set on this folder Sir?

Comment: Your permissions seems right : 644 should be enough. Check your webserver configuration (apache) or php.ini for anything that might deny file access?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `file_get_contents`, to get the file contents, and encode these contents with base64. Here is a good example I used in one of my projects:

```
$path = './images/approved.jpg';
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
```

Comment: I am having permission issues getting the file_get_contents. What should be the permissions on the folder. I have set them to 755 for the apache owner www-data.

Comment: Change the owner of the directory to be the user which PHP is running as, most probably the web server process